# assigned value has more bits then lvalue

Tags: c++, c, struct, compilation, bit-manipulation

Just out of curiosity. I want to know what happens when the lvalue has less bits then the assigned value.

```
char a = 0xffffFFFF
```

Moreover lets say

```
struct {
int num:3;
}testStruct;

testStruct.num = 0xffffFFFF/2 -1;
```

what will be the value in char (first case) and 3bit integer (in second case)

Comment: Congratulations on asking the question with `char`, as that adds another curlicue to the answer.

Comment: and dual-tagging, the answer differs in C than in C++

Comment: If that's the case I would love to know the different answer @MattMcNabb

Comment: One of the odd things about C is that `0xffffFFFF` _could_ be a _signed_ Hexadecimal constant instead of an unsigned one.  For this to be true though, `INT_MAX` would need to be >= `0xffffFFFF`.  Using the `u` suffix removes doubt: `0xffffFFFFu`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using the term "lvalue" incorrectly. I guess you mean "variable" or "object".

In the case `sizeof(0xFFFFFFFF) == 1` and plain char being `unsigned`, then `char a = 0xffffFFFF;` is straightforward, since that value can be represented in `char`.

In other cases, it is an *out-of-range conversion*.  If plain char is unsigned then this means the large positive number `0xFFFFFFFF` is adjusted modulo `UCHAR_MAX+1` to fit (on common systems, the plain char gets `255`).

If plain char is signed then it is implementation-defined behaviour (and in C, may raise an implementation-defined signal). The most common implementation definition is 2's complement truncation which would give the char the value `-1` but this is not guaranteed.

---

Moving onto the bitfield. `0xffffFFFF/2 - 1` is `0x7FFFFFFE`. This is assigned to a bitfield of type `int` and width `3`, which requests an out-of-range conversion, just like for the signed `char` case. As before, this is implementation-defined (and may raise an implementation-defined signal in C).

Look up your compiler documentation to find out what it specifies here, although I'd expect again that it would use 2's complement truncation, giving `-2`.

Comment: Good answer. You did not assume that char is 8 bits. Just `sizeof(char) = 1`.

Answer (score 3):

The value is preserved if the destination can store the value, else it is reduced modulo `CHAR_MAX + 1` if the destination is unsigned, otherwise the result is implementation-defined (C allows trapping though).

`char` might be able to store `0xFFFFFFFF` anyway, if `CHAR_BIT` is big enough.

---

C++14 (n3936):

> #### 3.9.1 Fundamental types `[basic.fundamental]`
>
> [...] In any particular implementation, a plain `char` object can take on either the same values as a `signed char` or an `unsigned char`; which one is implementation-defined.

> #### 4.7 Integral conversions `[conv.integral]`
>
> 1 A prvalue of an integer type can be converted to a prvalue of another integer type. A prvalue of an unscoped enumeration type can be converted to a prvalue of an integer type.
>   2 **If the destination type is unsigned**, the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the source integer (modulo 2n where n is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type).
>   3 **If the destination type is signed**, the value is unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type (and bit-field width); otherwise, the value is implementation-defined.
>   4 If the destination type is bool, see 4.12. If the source type is `bool`, the value `false` is converted to zero and the value `true` is converted to one.
>   5 The conversions allowed as integral promotions are excluded from the set of integral conversions.

---

C has rules which have nearly the same result, though observe that the last case may trap.
C11 (C99+amendments) (n1570):

> #### 6.2.5 Types
>
> 15 The three types `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned` char are collectively called
>   the character types. The implementation shall define `char` to have the same range,
>   representation, and behavior as either `signed char` or `unsigned char`.45)

> #### 6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers
>
> 1 When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than `_Bool`, if
>   the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged.
>   2 Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or
>   subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type
>   until the value is in the range of the new type.60)
>   3 Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the
>   result is implementation-defined **or an implementation-defined signal is raised**.

Answer (score 3):

If value does not fit for integral type (int, char, short, long etc):

1. **Signed**: The behaviour is implementation-defined.
2. **Unsigned**: Modular value is copied. (i.e. higher bits that can not be stored are ignored while copying)

Please note that `char` as used in your answer may behave as `signed char` or `unsigned char` depending upon your compiler and compilation flags.

> what will be the value in char (first case) and 3bit integer (in
>   second case)

The answer is implementation-dependent. Check your compiler documentation for exact answer that suits your environment.